# Problem comparing a tensor with binary values

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, one-class-classification

I have a problem where there is an image and a given question. The answer is of the form `[False, True]`. During training I try to find whether the prediction is right or wrong.

```py
def build_loss(logits, labels):
    # Cross-entropy loss
    loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels)

    # Classification accuracy
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss), accuracy

logits = C(self.img, self.q, scope='Classifier')
self.all_preds = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
self.loss, self.accuracy = build_loss(logits, self.a)
```

Assuming the original answer is `[0, 0]` and the predicted answer is `[0, 1]`, the `tf.argmax` for both, logits and labels would return a value of 1. Is there a way to avoid this ugly comparison? I tried replacing `tf.argmax` with `tf.reduce_max` but then accuracy always comes to be 0.

Or is there any other way to change the model, so that, rather than having 2 neurons in output layer I could get it done in 1 neuron. Currently, I am using `tf.nn.softmax` for finding the predictions and `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` as my loss function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use only one neuron at the end and use sigmoid activation in it.

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: But doing so the accuracy again becomes 0. Although in tensor board images I can see that prediction is working fine.